# How to give Char datatype in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to set a char datatype in nodejs model if it is possible. I try to my best for find that solution.
If not possible than please give me another way for doing it.

Thank you

**show error**

> char is not defined

**model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AdminSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },
    email: {
    type: Char,
    required: true
    },
    skype_id: {
    type: String
    },
    password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `String` type with a `maxlength` of `1`:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AdminSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 1
    },
    skype_id: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

More info on this can be found in [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here, some example datatype for you.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AdminSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, // String Format
        required: true // If required
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String // String format, but not required
    },
    favorite_number: {
      type: Number, // Number format
      get: v => Math.round( v ),
      set: v => Math.round( v ),
      alias: 'i'
    },
    ... // etc
});
```

Comment: I want example of char datatype so please give me answer for char datatype.